# File name that saved in document directory have space character

Tags: ios, swift, url, filepath

I want to download video file and save it in the **document directory** but when i try show that downloaded video, i can't create URL of that file.
i'm using this code for create path for save file. my file name have spacing : (mobileslider video.mp4), and i want to save this video with own name but i can't create url path that contain space. how can solve this problem?

if let url = URL(string:videoURL){

```
showVideoFromNib(nibURL:url)
```

}

when i try to remove space from videoURL, showVideoFromNib method called but don't show the video. and when use orginal url, showVideoFromNib method didn't call.

**Edit 1:**

i change destination path **from** :

```
 let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
```

**to** :

```
 let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
      let pathComponent = "pack\(self.packID)-\(selectRow + 1).mp4"
      let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
      let folderPath: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloads", isDirectory: true)
      let fileURL: URL = folderPath.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
      return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
```

now i can create URL and my show video method call but video don't show.
this is my new sample path:

/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2C2B6A39-5426-4E2C-B25A-CF64817AF26F/data/Containers/Data/Application/5A1BB109-D452-4F03-8820-EE1120E07C3D/Documents/Downloads/pack7-2.mp4

this file exist in this path but video player don't show this.

Answer (score 2):

I solve problem. i'm using

```
let path = destinationUrl.absoluteString
```

instead of

```
let path = destinationUrl.path
```